# Is it possible for Prometheus to capture metrics of each process in a large batch job?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

As per title, is it possible for Prometheus to capture metrics of each individual process in a large batch job?

This job runs hourly and processes records at a rate of about 500-1000 records/second, sending gauge metrics (unique to each record) to statsd_exporter for monitoring our SLOs.

however, i realized Prometheus can only capture as much as the scrape_interval allows, meaning its definitely missing some values sent to statsd_exporter (e.g possible missing some spikes in value).

Is there a way to overcome this? or perhaps i should be looking at some other tools instead.

updates: provided example of metrics sent. `job` label is limited to 10 different labels i.e 10 timeseries

```
# HELP time_taken_gauge Time taken for a particular job type to finish processing a record.
# TYPE time_taken_gauge gauge
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 123
time_taken_gauge{job="b"} 1314
time_taken_gauge{job="c"} 5435
time_taken_gauge{job="d"} 212
time_taken_gauge{job="e"} 231
time_taken_gauge{job="f"} 324
time_taken_gauge{job="g"} 15
time_taken_gauge{job="h"} 1213
time_taken_gauge{job="i"} 123
time_taken_gauge{job="j"} 1235
```

Only challenge is these are sent in at a much higher rate than Prometheus' scrape interval (1s), hence missing some records

```
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 123
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 1232 <- scraped
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 12412
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 53453 <- high value metric missed but potentially problematic
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 1564
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 756
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 34 <- scraped
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 15433
.
.
.
time_taken_gauge{job="a"} 345 <- scraped
```

Answer (score 1):

> 500-1000 records/second, sending gauge metrics (unique to each record)

That's going to be high cardinality. If you want a unique metric per record then you need an event logging system like ELK, not metrics systems like Prometheus or whatever you have statsd feeding into.

Comment: hey brian, thanks for your reply. i want to clarify something regarding "high cardinality". high cardinality will only be a problem if there's a large variance in metric labels? for my case, its kinda limited to about 10 different labels (e.g time_taken_to_create{job_type="a"} 123 | g), meaning i get at most 10 time series for the jobs running

Comment: i updated my original post with examples of metrics sent

Comment: How are you currently dealing with this in statsd? Because this isn't exactly something a metrics system can do.

Comment: Currently i configured server to send metrics to statsd_exporter after every single record is processed, failing to take into account that due to pull-based mechanism of Prometheus and the rate at which i am sending to statsd_exporter, metrics can be missed. i am unsure if there might be some ways to make this workable with Prometheus, favouring it because i find promQL really really useful

Comment: Another point I want to clarify is the sending of metrics isn't batched, meaning each metric sent is `ms` apart from each other in timestamp. Is there any possible way to store these metrics separately using another mechanism but still be able to use promQL for analysis?

Comment: What you describe won't work with statsd either as I understand it. You might want to rethink exactly what your metrics are. For gauges only the current value is of interest.

Comment: my purpose for measuring the time_taken is to 1. see the overall trend of how long it takes for each job to complete in order to propose a SLO 2. to be alerted on any exceptionally high value

alternatively, maybe i can consider using a counter instead that increments whenever time taken for a particular job exceeds a certain value

Answer (score -1):

The way to overcome short-lived jobs, or slow jobs is to use a Pushgateway, which will store all metrics pushes to it and expose them to be scraped.

This is the standard for handling such cases, I'm not familiar with alternatives..Be happy to.

> The Prometheus Pushgateway exists to allow ephemeral and batch jobs to
>   expose their metrics to Prometheus. Since these kinds of jobs may not
>   exist long enough to be scraped, they can instead push their metrics
>   to a Pushgateway. The Pushgateway then exposes these metrics to
>   Prometheus.

https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway

Comment: Pushgateway doesn't work because the limitation seems to be on Prometheus' scrape interval. If I have metrics being sent at a rate of up to 500 data points/second and Prometheus'  scrape interval is 1s, it will capture only a few data points every single time it pulls from pushgateway/statsd, which isn't the desired behaviour